# How to find the mystery person walking around

Tags: the-stanley-parable

I've seen several screenshots of a mysterious person that you can spot while playing the Stanley Parable.
Does anybody know where exactly you find this person?

Comment: Why don't you post these screenshots here?

Comment: The game name doesn't need to be in the title; the tag takes care of it rather neatly.

Comment: Yes, but it looks unappealing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a video of the mystery person:

As far as anyone can tell, obtaining him is just another random event in the game.

Some people believe he is [Employee 432](http://www.reddit.com/r/stanleyparable/comments/1t07f2/employee_432/), who is referenced on papers and whiteboards throughout the game.  However, nothing is really known about who he is or what he does.  You can visit the above link for lots of crazy theories, though.